# Slide Down/Up animation not working with list items. CSS - Ionic 2

Tags: css, typescript, animation, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a list, when clicking that list there should be a drop down animation to view the items underneath the selected item. Currently, it just populates and displays without an animation.

Note: .item-accordion.hidden { line-height: 0px; } and toggling the class on your component  does not work either.

Here's an example of what I want to achieve but it's with Ionic 1. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgYoaL

CSS

```
.item-accordion{ line-height: 25px; transition: .09s all linear; }
.item-accordion [hidden]{ line-height: 0px; }
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i; odd as isOdd; even as isEven">
    <ion-item-sliding id="rightdiv" >
      <button ion-item (click)="toggleGroup(i)"  [ngClass]="{active: isGroupShown(i)}" class="destInfo">
        <h3>click for more info</h3>
      </button>

      <ion-item [hidden]="!isGroupShown(i)" class="details item-accordion">
        <ion-label item-left>something</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item [hidden]="!isGroupShown(i)" class="details item-accordion">
        <ion-label item-left>something</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item [hidden]="!isGroupShown(i)" class="detail-button item-accordion" >
        <button>click me</button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-item-sliding>
```

TYPESCRIPT

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ModalController, AlertController, ItemSliding, Nav } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Items } from '../../providers/providers';
import { Item } from '../../models/item';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-list-master',
  templateUrl: 'rider-master.html'
})
export class RiderMasterPage {
  items: Item[];
  index: number;
  shownGroup = null;
  isInactiveOne: boolean = false; 
  isInactiveTwo: boolean = true; 
  activeItemSliding: ItemSliding = null;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public items: Items, public modalCtrl: ModalController, private el: ElementRef, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    this.items = this.items.query();

  }

  /**
   * The view loaded, let's query our items for the list
   */
  ionViewDidLoad() {
  }

toggleGroup(group){
  if (this.isGroupShown(group)){
    this.shownGroup = null;
  } else {
    this.shownGroup = group;
  }
}
isGroupShown(group){
  return this.shownGroup === group;
};


}
```

Comment: seems to be working fine to me.. just increased the transition time to see it better.. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwjdvw

Comment: Yes, that example is working for me. However, that's an example from Ionic 1, not 2. The code I posted above is what I'm using and the way it is done here doesn't seem to convert.